# Create a copy of an old revision of a file using Dropbox API

Tags: dropbox-api

I’m trying to use the Dropbox API to create a copy of an older revision of a file.

The use case is that the user browses his files, picks one and lists its revisions, picks one of the revisions and copies it to some folder in his account.

However, as far as I can tell, the copy method in the API only accepts a source path and there’s no way to specify a revision. I tried passing a revision in the path as is supported in download, but that fails.

Therefore, I could only think of the following workarounds:

1. Use restore to rollback the source file to the desired revision, copy it to the destination folder , and restore it back to the original revision
2. Download the desired revision and upload it to the destination folder

I don’t like solution #1 because if something goes wrong during the process, the user may end up with an older revision of the original file. Solution #2 does a redundant download and upload.

Can anyone suggest a better way to implement this functionality?

Comment: The Dropbox API doesn't offer a good way to do this unfortunately, but we'll consider it a feature request.

Comment: @Greg Thanks for your reply! Do you have somewhere I could submit this as a feature request and follow up on it?

Comment: We don't have a public feature request tracker, but I've filed this internally.

Comment: @Greg Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Greg anything yet? I would like to do this as well.

Comment: No news on this request.